# ¿Como evaluar si el comando anterior ha fallado en csh?

Tags: unix, csh

Tengo un script que ejecuta varios comandos. Y hay uno que quiero verificar si ha fallado y si es así mostrar un mensaje y acabar.

En bash usaría $?

¿Qué tengo que usar en csh?

Comment: me parece bien que te autocontestes pero deberias añadir mas informacion en la pregunta. Al igual que harias si quieres que alguien te la consteste.

Comment: ¿Y qué información falta?

Comment: "Tengo un script que ejecuta varios comandos.". pues por ejemplo poner parte de tu código como le pediriamos a cualquiera que haga una pregunta así.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En csh puedes usar [$status](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Special_shell_variables.html#status)

```
comando1
if ( $status != 0 ) then
  echo "Ha fallado el comando1"
  exit 1
endif
comando2
```